# How can I use server-side Redux in Next.js v13.0 with the help of app directory?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

can we use Redux with Next.js v13 by using app directory? just like before, using the Next.js Redux wrapper.
or if we can use then, is there any example available to use server-side Redux in Next.js 13?

I am going to use new Next.js v13 because of new layout update so, can we create a server side state by using app directory?

It seems that they are already using Redux, but if I implemented Redux as per the source code, then I am receiving the error of React createContext.

what should I do? What would the code be in an online editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Next.js beta documentation:

> In Next.js 13, context is fully supported within **Client Components**,
> but it cannot be created or consumed directly within Server
> Components.

```
'use client';

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const SidebarContext = createContext();

export function Sidebar() {
  const [isOpen,*emphasized text* setIsOpen] = useState();

  return (
    <SidebarContext.Provider value={{ isOpen }}>
      <SidebarNav />
    </SidebarContext.Provider>
  );
}

function SidebarNav() {
  let { isOpen } = useContext(SidebarContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Home</p>

      {isOpen && <Subnav />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

More details are here: [Next.js documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#context)

[Another user asked about the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368348/does-redux-still-makes-sense-with-nextjs-13-app-directory).

Comment: but when I installed nextjs 13 and run it, it seems that nextjs 13 is allready using redux, I noticed in the redux extension devtool before doing anything.

Comment: Someone asked the same question but this is still question yet to be resolved, he just that we can achieve this thing but he hasn't posted full source code that we can try it on online IDE like ( codesandbox ).